# Adding Alpine attributes to Django's form fields

Tags: django, alpine.js

I'm rendering django template form fields this way :

```
<div x-data="{ amount: 0 }">
    {% render_field field class=class %}
</div>
```

I want to add to the input : `x-on:input.change="console.log('test');"`

1. How can I add this to `render_field` ?
   In forms.py as
    `widgets = { 'amount': forms.TextInput(attrs={'x-on:input.change': "console.log('test');" }) }`
    the only way ?
2. Is there a way to add `x-on:input.change` via JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add:

```
attrs={'onChange':"yourJavaScriptFunction(this.id)"} #You can pass arguments about 'this', for example.
```

Then just add the function in your template, or js.